# Dynamic directories and files like wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

In wordpress there are directories which actually do not exists. 
like example.com/post/name-of-the-post actually opens a main php file which fetches the content of that posts from database. 
How can i implement this natively on linux apache php server without wordpress?

Comment: its done with Apache mod_rewrite : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [use .htaccess](http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk/). This is the technology behind Wordpress' ability to do what you are wanting to do.

[Here are the docs from apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

[Also here's a nice Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people use mod_rewrite, it is overkill for most tasks. For most things there are more nimble modules available. That is not to deny mod_rewrite, it has its place, but I find it is over used. In this particular case you can use mod_alias, no need for mod_rewrite. E.g.

```
AliasMatch ^/post/(.*) /real/path/post.php$1
```

module docs here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

This doc beautifully outlines when NOT to use mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html